# How to check if time passed or not when game re-opened?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The coroutine runs when "tebs" variable gets some value through the game. And while it works, it sets `timeScale` to zero and waiting for a while and then the game keeps continue.

The problem is that i want to game checks the real time/local time when the game closed and re-opened and compare them to check if the time passed or not, so coroutine keeps running or ends.

```
IEnumerator TEBSWait()
    {
        //INK PLUGIN VARIABLE THAT DETERMINES THE SECONDS TO WAIT
        int tebs = (int)_inkStory.variablesState["TEBS"];

        //SAVE GAME
        Debug.Log("tebsSaved");
        var savedState = _inkStory.state.ToJson();
        PlayerPrefs.SetString("tebsSaved", savedState);

        //STOP TIME & WAIT FOR A WHILE 
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(tebs * 60); 
        Time.timeScale = 1;

        PlayerPrefs.DeleteKey("tebsSaved");
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you multiplying with `60` in the `WaitForSecondsRealtime` constructor? If `tebs` is equal to `1`, you'll be waiting `60` seconds. Is this intentional? If `tebs` is a value higher than `1`, it just gets much worse :-).

Comment: Yes, it is intentional. That's because in "Ink" story file, the `tebs` time wrote for minutes, so i am multiplying with `60`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user loses focus or quits the app, save the current time. When the user returns load the previous time and compare it with the current time. Doing this will give you the difference in time.

In my example, I save ticks to the PlayerPrefs. Keep in mind that `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks` is a `long`, and PlayerPrefs can only take `int` for numeric values, so I had to store it as a `string`.

```
void Awake()
{
    Load();
}

void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    Save();
}

void OnApplicationFocus(bool hasFocus)
{
    if (hasFocus) Load();
    else Save();
}

void Load()
{
    long nowTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
    long prevTicks = nowTicks;

    string prevTicksString = PlayerPrefs.GetString("ticks", string.Empty);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prevTicksString)) prevTicks = long.Parse(prevTicksString);

    double secondsPassed = TimeSpan.FromTicks(nowTicks - prevTicks).TotalSeconds;

    Debug.Log(secondsPassed);
}

void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("ticks", DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString());
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Comment: *`Keep in mind that DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks is a long, and PlayerPrefs can only take int for numeric values`* And this is why you don't use PlayerPrefs for this. Use your own serialization system as PlayerPrefs was not meant to handle things that were not ***user preferences.***

Comment: @Draco18s agreed.

Comment: Good answer, one small addition is that we store the actual date serialized to JSON, and then you don't have the int/long issue of working with ticks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`WaitUntil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitUntil.html).

Example:

```cs
DateTime until = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(5);

yield return new WaitUntil(() => DateTime.UtcNow >= until);
```

Comment: i replaced this snippet with my `//STOP TIME & WAIT FOR A WHILE ` part and also changed `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);` part to `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(tebs * 60);` it doesnt pause the game. Also tried with putting different values as seconds but the result is same. Where do i mistake  you think ?

Comment: First of all, you could use `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(tebs)`. Secondly, how are you calling `TEBSWait()`? The game should be paused for sure, unless you call the coroutine in some odd manner. What do you mean, exactly, that the game does not pause?

Comment: Your entire answer can be replaced with [`yield return WaitForSecondsRealtime(5)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSecondsRealtime.html)

Comment: I tried to modify it in my coroutine but it did not worked when re-opened the game. But your advice gave me an idea anyway, thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Draco18s that's what I thought at first, too. But if you see his original question; you'll see that he was already using `WaitForSecondsRealtime` - that's why I proposed this way of handling it.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to calculate the time between the closing and re-opening of the game you can use `DateTime`. Call `DateTime.Now` when the game closes and when it re-opens use it again and calculate the difference.

Comment: Used same logic with other reply and solved, thanks for the reply!