# can't reset specfic playerprefs in unity3d

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, timer, 3d

I have made 2 codes to manage my interstitial ads by making the ads show every 5 mins when the player losses but the problem is that I tried to reset them when the player passes the 5 mins and press the button when he losses but it didn't work so how to reset the timer when the player presses the button?

this is the 1st code :

> ```
> public int LastShownIntTime = 300;
>
>
>
> void Start()
> {
>     #if UNITY_ANDROID
>     Advertisement.Initialize(androidID);
>      #endif
> }
> public void Update()
> {
>
>     LastShownIntTime = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LastShownIntTime");
>
> }     
> public void showInterstitial()
> {
>     if (LastShownIntTime <=0)
>     {
>         showInterstitialwith5mint();
>     }
> }
>
> public void showInterstitialwith5mint()
> {
>     Advertisement.Show("video");
>     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastShownIntTime", 300);
> }
> ```

and the 2nd one :

> ```
> public float LastShownIntTimefloat;
>  public int LastShownIntTime = 300;
>
> void Start()
> {
>     LastShownIntTime = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("LastShownIntTime");
>     LastShownIntTimefloat = LastShownIntTime;
>
> }
> public void Update()
> {
>
>     LastShownIntTimefloat -= Time.deltaTime;
>     LastShownIntTime = (int)LastShownIntTimefloat;
>     PlayerPrefs.SetInt("LastShownIntTime", LastShownIntTime);
>
> }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: [Here's an answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57509475/how-to-check-if-time-passed-or-not-when-game-re-opened/57511214#57511214).

Comment: You dont show the playerprefs being actually saved.

Comment: @BugFinder From [`PlayerPrefs.Save`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.Save.html) `By default Unity writes preferences to disk during OnApplicationQuit(). In cases when the game crashes or otherwise prematuraly exits, you might want to write the PlayerPrefs at sensible 'checkpoints' in your game. This function will write to disk potentially causing a small hiccup, therefore it is not recommended to call during actual gameplay.`

Comment: Well, if it silently barfs the values arent saved..

Answer (score 1):

The main issue here:

**You would have to reset the `LastShownIntTimefloat` in your *script2!***

Otherwise you simply continue overwriting it with new values reducing the value more and write it back to `PlayerPrefs`

→ the next time your *script1* polls the value it is not reset but already overwritten by *script2*!

---

In general: **You should not use `PlayerPrefs` in order to make two components communicate!**

In your case here I wouldn't even separate the logic and bother with implementing the communication between them but rather **merge them into one single component.**

Then it is not necessary to read and write `PlayerPrefs` **every frame** but rather only on certain checkpoints like

- Read **once** in `Start`
- Write **once** in `OnApplicationQuit`
- Write **once** in `OnDestroy` (This is for the case you e.g. switch Scene but don't quit the app)
- Write **once** ever time your user loses (`showInterstitial` is called)
- Write **once** when resetting the value after showing the advertisement

I would also simply directly use a `float` and `GetFloat` and `SetFloat` instead of converting it from and to an `int`.

```
public class MergedClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Rather sue a FLOAT for time!
    public float LastShownTime = 300;

    void Start()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        Advertisement.Initialize(androidID);
#endif

        // use 300 as default value if no PlayerPrefs found
        LastShownTime = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("LastShownTime", 300f);
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if(LastShownTime > 0f) LastShownTime -= Time.deltaTime;
    }     

    public void showInterstitial()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("LastShownTime", LastShownTime);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        if (LastShownTime <= 0f)
        {
            showInterstitialwith5mint();
        }
    }
    
    public void showInterstitialwith5mint()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        Advertisement.Show("video");
#else

        LastShownTime = 300f;
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("LastShownTime", LastShownTime); 
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void OnApplicationQuit()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("LastShownTime", LastShownTime);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("LastShownTime", LastShownTime);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Mohamad no, why would you want to `DeleteAll` playerprefs? You only want to reset the existing one. Imagine having a huge system and multiple objects accessing and changing playerprefs .. you wouldn't want to generally delete all prefs just to reset one value ;)